# how to count with multiple criteria in mongo php

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm newbie in mongodb. I think there is some usage differences between mongo shell and php mongo driver.

I can count with multiple criteria in mongo shell. For example:

```
db.coll.count( { _id:ObjectId('4fb27b9c876b88e53d000000'), 
                 'items.title':'example' } );
```

But I can't make the same counting with php mongo driver. I tried this but it returns 0.

```
$coll->count( array('_id'=>new MongoID('4fb27b9c876b88e53d000000'), 
                    'items.title'=>'example' ) );
```

However, if I use find() and then count(), I get the same counting result:

```
$coll->find( array('_id'=>new MongoID('4fb27b9c876b88e53d000000'), 
                   'items.title'=>'example' ) ).count();
```

I get what I want, but I think the chaining way might be inefficient. Am I wrong?

How can you count with multiple criteria?

Comment: Just to clarify, you have a collection in your mongo database called 'coll' and a field within the collection called 'items' pointing to a sub-document with a field called 'title'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One code sample is worth a thousand words. Look:

```
% mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.1.1
connecting to: test
> db.foo.count
function (x) {
    return this.find(x).count();
}
```

Did this answer your question? :)

Comment: I can count with multiple criteria in mongo shell, I don't have problem with this. But how can I do the same thing from php? In addition, I choosed to use the chaining way because I've heard  find().count() and count() are identical.

Comment: That's what I was trying to say. Use `find().count()`, there should be no penalty if the driver is implemented correctly (and I believe it is).

Answer (score 0):

You must first use find() and than count()

```
db.foo.count() -- will return 0, because db.foo it is only accessing the collection

db.foo.find($where).count() --- will return the number of documents in the collection
```

This is how to do it.